# JQuery UI Draggable not working with my app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, user-interface

I am trying to make the blankWindow class draggable and the handle has to be #blankWindowHandle. I downloaded my custom download of JQuery UI and nothing is working. it is still just highlighting the text in the top of the handle element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ModularWiz_B</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/icon.png">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/startup.png">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js">    </script>
        <script>
            var online = navigator.onLine;
            $(document).ready(function() {
            if (online == false) {
            $('#wifiwarning').fadeToggle("fast");
        };
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $( ".blankWindow" ).draggable({ handle: "#blankWindowHandle" });
        // getter
        var handle = $( ".blankWindow" ).draggable( "option", "handle" );
        // setter
        $( ".blankWindow" ).draggable( "option", "handle", "#blankWindowHandle" );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="addButton">
        <img src="images/add.png" alt="Add" onClick="$('#appMkt').fadeToggle('fast');"/>
    </div>
    <appWindow id='appMkt'>
        <div class="close" onClick="$('#appMkt').fadeToggle('fast');"></div>
        ~APPS~<HR/>
        <div onClick="$('.blankWindow').fadeToggle('fast');$('#appMkt').fadeToggle('fast');"><img src="images/icon.png"> .blankWindow()</div><hr/>
        <div onClick="$('.info').fadeToggle('fast');$('#appMkt').fadeToggle('fast');"><img src="images/icon.png"> App Info</div>
    </appWindow>
    <appWindow class="blankWindow">
        <div class="appClose" onClick="$('.blankWindow').fadeToggle('fast');"></div>
        <center id="blankWindowHandle">
           ~Blank~<hr/>
        </center>
       This is a .blankWindow<br/><br/>
       We can use this to house the apis (apps).
    </appWindow>
    <appWindow class="info">
        <div class="close" onClick="$('.info').fadeToggle('fast');"></div>
        ~INFO~<HR/>
        <a rel="license" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0;width:88px;height:31px;" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nd/4.0/88x31.png" /></a><br /><span xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" href="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/InteractiveResource" property="dct:title" rel="dct:type">ModularWiz</span> is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License</a>.<hr/>
        Developed by:<br/> ... and ...<hr/>
    </appWindow>
    <div id="wifiwarning">
    <!-- NOTE: THIS DIV ALWAYS NEEDS TO BE THE VERY LAST THING ON THE PAGE INSIDE THE BODY TAGS -->
        <br />
        <br />
        You need to be connected to the internet to use this app.
        <br />
        Please try going to settings and toggling wifi on
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS code may be executing before the DOM is created. Try using $(document).ready(function(){}); or its abbreviation $(function(){}); to make sure that your JS runs after your DOM is created. You can also place your JS on the bottom of the body so you make sure the JS runs right after the DOM is created.

UPDATED: As I suggested you, I placed your JS at the bottom of the body and it worked fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ModularWiz_B</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/icon.png">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/startup.png">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">

</head>
<body>
<div id="addButton">
        <img src="images/add.png" alt="Add" onClick="$('#appMkt').fadeToggle('fast');"/>
    </div>
    <appWindow id='appMkt'>
        <div class="close" onClick="$('#appMkt').fadeToggle('fast');"></div>
        ~APPS~<HR/>
        <div onClick="$('.blankWindow').fadeToggle('fast');$('#appMkt').fadeToggle('fast');"><img src="images/icon.png"> .blankWindow()</div><hr/>
        <div onClick="$('.info').fadeToggle('fast');$('#appMkt').fadeToggle('fast');"><img src="images/icon.png"> App Info</div>
    </appWindow>
    <appWindow class="blankWindow ui-draggable">
        <div class="appClose" onClick="$('.blankWindow').fadeToggle('fast');"></div>
        <center id="blankWindowHandle">
           ~Blank~<hr/>
        </center>
       This is a .blankWindow<br/><br/>
       We can use this to house the apis (apps).
    </appWindow>
    <appWindow class="info">
        <div class="close" onClick="$('.info').fadeToggle('fast');"></div>
    ~INFO~<HR/>
        <a rel="license" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0;width:88px;height:31px;" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nd/4.0/88x31.png" /></a><br /><span xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" href="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/InteractiveResource" property="dct:title" rel="dct:type">ModularWiz</span> is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License</a>.<hr/>
    Developed by:<br/> ... and ...<hr/>
        </appWindow>
        <div id="wifiwarning">
    <!-- NOTE: THIS DIV ALWAYS NEEDS TO BE THE VERY LAST THING ON THE PAGE INSIDE THE BODY TAGS -->
        <br />
        <br />
        You need to be connected to the internet to use this app.
        <br />
        Please try going to settings and toggling wifi on
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var online = navigator.onLine;
        $(document).ready(function() {
        if (online == false) {
        $('#wifiwarning').fadeToggle("fast");
        };
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $( ".blankWindow" ).draggable({ handle: "#blankWindowHandle" });
        // getter
        var handle = $( ".blankWindow" ).draggable( "option", "handle" );
        // setter
        $( ".blankWindow" ).draggable( "option", "handle", "#blankWindowHandle" );
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I will do a better debug when I get home I promise :D

Comment: Thanks! This is why I like these tech communities... Everyone is so friendly and helpful :)

Comment: One question, what is that appWindow tag you are using?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! Im not sure why it didnt work for me. I exactly what you told me to do, and it didnt work, until I copied your code into my document. as for the `<appWindow></appWindow>` tag, I made that myself and imported it into the document via the css file.

Comment: You dont have to figure this one out for me, but now I am wondering if there is a way to make this work on an apple mobile iDevice such as an iPod Touch or iPad...

Comment: I will research that and try it out in my iPhone, I promise :)